# How to use trained siamese network to predict labels for large test set with 100+ classes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, image-comparison, siamese-network

Do I have to compare each test image to an example image from each class? The test set contains around 7400 images across 104 classes. So this would be 7400 x 104 predictions?

Using tensorflow on tpu's I was able to train the model pretty effectively. However, predicting the labels using the above method takes very long and additionally the model predict call causes memory leaks that eventually cause the kernel to fail (memory can blow up to 30+gb and counting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this :

- (No recommended) This is
  basically subset of of what you're actually doing. You can take some
  images from each class and compare it with your test image. Lets say
  you select 5 images from every class so you'll have to do 5*104
  predictions.
- You can use K - Nearest Neighbor model where you'll have to do the prediction of your 7400(or subset of these) images once only i.e create a KNN model and then directly use KNN Classifier to predict the class of the image.

You can also refer to the [Blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-shot-learning-with-siamese-networks-using-keras-17f34e75bb3d) if you dont have a lot of idea about KNN or want to look at code implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the response Akash!  Quick follow up questions: I've been using this link as a reference and it looks like your first bullet point (my current approach) is equivalent to the model validating in section 9.  In section 10, kNN is mentioned but the model isnt utilized. Could you elaborate on how to link the trained siamese to this kNN mentioned?  Am I getting the vectors from the top cnn layer and then incorporating the kNN ?

Comment: another thought, or maybe after training the neural network, I generate feature vectors for the labeled train set and the unlabeled test set.  then I train a kNN classifier on the labeled train vectors and then predict on the unlabeled test vectors?

Comment: Yes absolutely. 
1. Train Siamese with training data and validate on validation data.
2. Get vectors from the the trained model for all the data you you. 
3. Use KNN model to build model using these vectors. 
4. Get vectors of a new image.
5. Use KNN classifier technique to predict the class of this data point.

Comment: thank you! this gave me a lot of guidance. had a follow up that doesn't have much context, but you may still have some insight.  My siamese model is getting about 0.84 AUC on the validation set.  however, knn is getting about ~26% accuracy.  is this reasonable?  I know 0.84 Auc isn't great but I was hoping to see better than 26% accuracy classifying

Comment: Did you try playing with the value of K ?

Comment: I did yeah, went extremes on both low and high end and I could definitely cause the accuracy to drop but raising it above 30% is not happening.  im training the original model a bit better and generating vectors of different lengths to see if I can change the outcome.  I imagine I could use these feature vectors with another conv net  and treat it as dimensionality reduction but not sure if thatll beat just using something like efficient net from the jump.